# Spring Cloud Stream - Can't get configured kafka's broker address

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I'm trying register manually a kafka listener using Spring Cloud Stream, however I'm facing some problems when trying to connect to broker:

```
[Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=h2r] Initialize connection to node localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) for sending metadata request
[Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=h2r] Initiating connection to node localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null)
[Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=h2r] Node -1 disconnected.
[Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=h2r] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=h2r] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
```

It is trying connect in localhost:9092 but my server is in another computer (192.168.1.200:9092), what am I doing wrong in this configuration:

```
@Service
public class TenantMessageConsumer {

private final String defaultEnterpriseSchema;
private final MailService mailService;
private final KafkaListenerContainerFactory containerFactory;
private final KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

public TenantMessageConsumer(String defaultEnterpriseSchema, MailService mailService, KafkaListenerContainerFactory containerFactory, KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry) {
    this.defaultEnterpriseSchema = defaultEnterpriseSchema;
    this.mailService = mailService;
    this.containerFactory = containerFactory;
    this.registry = registry;
    listen();
}


public void listen() {
    TenantMessageConsumer that=this;
    AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint endpoint=new AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint<String, Object>() {
        @Override
        protected MessagingMessageListenerAdapter createMessageListener(MessageListenerContainer container, MessageConverter messageConverter) {
            try {
                return new RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter(that,TenantMessageConsumer.class.getMethod("process",Object.class));
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    };
    endpoint.setId("tenant");
    endpoint.setTopics(defaultEnterpriseSchema);
    endpoint.setGroupId("h2r");
    registry.registerListenerContainer(endpoint,containerFactory);
}

public void process(Object message){
    if (message instanceof SimpleEmailMessage) {
        SimpleEmailMessage emailMessage = (SimpleEmailMessage) message;
        if (emailMessage.getContent().equals("reset-password"))
            mailService.sendPasswordResetMail(emailMessage);
    }
}
}
```

It is supposed to get this configuration:

```
spring:
    cloud:
        stream:
            kafka:
                binder:
                    brokers: 192.168.1.200
```

So, what I need is a way to get the configured broker address and set it in endpoint object.

**Important**

As the topic name is dynamic, I can't use annotations like @StreamListener.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't describe your problem nor have you provided any relevant information such as stack trace, logs etc,. (please do in the future), but I'll try.

You absolutely can use `@StreamListener` and other annotations  with Spring Cloud Stream's support for [dynamic destinations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/#dynamicdestination).

Please go through the above section and let us know if you still need help.

Comment: I've done the same configuration in the link, but in my producer microservice. What I want in this case, is receive the messages generated in dynamic topic.

Comment: In the above link, there is an example with `SourceWithDynamicDestination` where you can see the injected `BinderAwareChannelResolver` and so on. Have you looked at that? I mean there is a full example as well as reference to an actual and existing application that uses it - "Router Sink Application".

Comment: I've already read this example, and it only create dynamic routes for producers. `BinderAwareChannelResolver` method `resolveDestination` returns a `MessageChannel` but I need a `SubscribableMessageChannel`

Comment: Did you actually look at `SourceWithDynamicDestination` example and the Router Sink Application that is referenced there? Those are consumers. . .